# GKE Maximum persistent disks per node

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I got an error creating a pod with pvc

```
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-xxx" : googleapi: Error 400: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION - Maximum persistent disks count should be less than [4]
```

I have a custom type instance node with 1vCPU / 3G RAM. And truly, this instance already has 4 other PVC attached.

But according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#increased_persistent_disk_limits) page, there shouldn't be error

> For custom machine types or predefined machine types that have a minimum of 1 vCPU, you can attach up to 128 persistent disks.

What am I missing? What else to check?

I checked GCloud quotas but didn't find such metrics (found only PD size)

Comment: I hit this issue a few days ago as well, and I'm going nuts trying to figure out what is going on. Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

You stumbled on an issue we had noticed, we just fixed it today. If you re-deploy you should be able to add your 5 pvc’s and more without any problem.